# Cannot Set Partition ReadOnly in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use a Powershell Script to Set USB Drives Readonly.
So I looked up on TechNet and found the sample:[Set-Partition cmdlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848710(v=wps.630).aspx). However it doesn't work.

Here's the sample:

```
 Set-Partition -DriveLetter H  -IsReadOnly $false
```

However, it came up with an error saying:

```
Set-Partition : Not Supported
Activity ID: {76b6e385-31a4-4935-95ed-0703d1a442b9}
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-Partition -DriveLetter H  -IsReadOnly $true
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (StorageWMI:ROOT/Microsoft/..._StorageCmdlets) [Set-Partition]，CimException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 1,Set-Partition
```

I'm running on Windows 10 1607 Professional.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Could you mark the entire drive as read-only? If needs to be on the Partition and it NTFS, you could set the permissions in the ACL.

Here's the one liner for setting it for the entire drive

```
get-disk -Number (Get-Partition -DriveLetter H).disknumber | Set-Disk -IsReadOnly $true
```