# C# Check if pendrive is read-only and run DISKPART to change readonly status

Tags: c#, readonly-attribute, diskpart

I'm quite lost with this task. Basically I have to check if a pendrive has readonly property.

- If it's protected I have to unprotect it (we use DISKPART.exe), update some files, then protect it again.
- If it's not protected, I just have to update files then protect it again.

This is my code:

```
private void protectpendrive(string disk)
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;   
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\diskpart.exe";   
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;                    
            p.Start();
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("select volume " + disk);
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("attributes disk set readonly");
            debugListView.Items.Add(DateTime.Now + "Pendrive is now read-only.");
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
        }
```

To unprotect:

```
private void unprotectpendrive(string disk)
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;   
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\diskpart.exe";   
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;                    
            p.Start();
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("select volume " + disk);
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("attributes disk clear readonly");
            debugListView.Items.Add(DateTime.Now + "Pendrive is now not protected.");
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
        }
```

This is my control for the current status, but it doesn't work either:

```
        private bool checkreadonly(string disk)
        {
            DirectoryInfo pendrive = new DirectoryInfo(disk);
            if (pendrive.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.ReadOnly))
            {
                debugListView.Items.Add(DateTime.Now + " Pendrive is read-only.");
                return true;
            }
            debugListView.Items.Add(DateTime.Now + " Pendrive is writable.");
            return false;
        }
```

The issues I have are:

1. Diskpart requires administrator priviledges, I tried with StartInfo.Verb="runas" but it seems it's not taken into consideration
2. If I launch my app with administrator rights, the diskpart window opens but it doesn't close at the end. Overall the status doesn't change.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: diskpart runs as its own sub-shell in the shell process, so it can be tricky to use in general.  I would suggest writing a diskpart script or using the CIM (previously WMI) interface directly to interact with the drive instead which will give you programmatic access.

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71344930/10024425) should be helpful.

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid I'd argue that's an XY problem to hammer in a solution you know versus the _correct_ solution of interacting with the drive programmatically.  It's almost always the wrong tool to shell out.  e.g., [`Cim-DiskDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/cim-diskdrive)

Comment: Probably much much easier to do this using Powershell or CIM/WMI. In Powershell you can do `(Get-Partition -DriveLetter $driveletter | Get-Disk).IsReadOnly` etc

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40118104/10024425

Answer (score 0):

The following shows how to both set and clear the readonly attribute for a removable USB disk.

**Create a new `Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)` project** (name: ProcessDiskPartTest)

**Add an Application Manifest to your project**

**Note**: This is used to prompt the user to execute the program as Administrator.

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add New Item...**
- Select **Application Manifest File (Windows Only)** (name: app.manifest)
- Click **Add**

In **app.manifest**, replace

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

with

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

---

**Option 1** - Diskpart (script)

The following shows how to create a [diskpart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart) script and then use [System.Diagnostics.Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.8) to execute the script.

**Add the following using directives**:

- `using System.IO;`
- `using System.Diagnostics;`

The following code will use [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.8) to execute a `diskpart` script.

```
public void RunDiskPartScript(string scriptText)
{
    string diskpartPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "System32", "diskpart.exe");

    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(diskpartPath))
        throw new Exception(String.Format("'{0}' doesn't exist.", diskpartPath));

    Debug.WriteLine("diskpartPath: " + diskpartPath);

    ProcessStartInfo psInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(diskpartPath);

    string scriptFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
    Debug.WriteLine($"scriptFilename: '{scriptFilename}'");

    //save script
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(scriptFilename, scriptText);

    psInfo.Arguments = $"/s {scriptFilename}";

    psInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    psInfo.RedirectStandardError = true; //redirect standard Error
    psInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; //redirect standard output
    psInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
    psInfo.UseShellExecute = false; //if True, uses 'ShellExecute'; if false, uses 'CreateProcess'
    psInfo.Verb = "runas"; //use elevated permissions
    psInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

    //create new instance and set properties
    using (Process p = new Process() { EnableRaisingEvents = true, StartInfo = psInfo })
    {
        //subscribe to event and add event handler code
        p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                //ToDo: add desired code 
                Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Data);
            }
        };

        //subscribe to event and add event handler code
        p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                //ToDo: add desired code
                Debug.WriteLine("Output: " + e.Data);
            }
        };

        p.Start(); //start

        p.BeginErrorReadLine(); //begin async reading for standard error
        p.BeginOutputReadLine(); //begin async reading for standard output

        //waits until the process is finished before continuing
        p.WaitForExit();

        if (File.Exists(scriptFilename))
            File.Delete(scriptFilename); //delete file
    }
}

public void SetDiskProperty(string driveLetter, bool isReadOnly)
{
    //create diskpart script text
    StringBuilder sbScript = new StringBuilder();
    sbScript.AppendLine($"select volume {driveLetter}");

    if (isReadOnly)
        sbScript.AppendLine($"attributes disk set readonly");
    else
        sbScript.AppendLine($"attributes disk clear readonly");

    //Debug.WriteLine($"Script:\n'{sbScript.ToString()}'");

    //execute script
    RunDiskPartScript(sbScript.ToString());
}
```

**Usage** (Clear Readonly):

```
 //The drive letter can be one of the following formats: `H`, `H:`, or `H:\`
SetDiskProperty("H:\", false);
```

**Usage** (Set Readonly):

```
 //The drive letter can be one of the following formats: `H`, `H:`, or `H:\`
 SetDiskProperty("H", true);
```

---

**Option 2** - Diskpart (StandardInput)

The following shows how to call *diskpart* by using [System.Diagnostics.Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.8) and sending commands via [StandardInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput?view=net-7.0)

**Add the following using directives**:

- `using System.IO;`
- `using System.Diagnostics;`

```
public static void DiskClearReadOnly(string driveLetter)
{
    List<string> commands = new List<string>() { $"select volume {driveLetter}", "attributes disk clear readonly", "exit" };
    RunDiskPart(commands);

    Debug.WriteLine($"Disk '{driveLetter}' is now read-write.");
}

public static void DiskSetReadOnly(string driveLetter)
{
    List<string> commands = new List<string>() { $"select volume {driveLetter}", "attributes disk set readonly", "exit" };
    RunDiskPart(commands);

    Debug.WriteLine($"Disk '{driveLetter}' is now read-only.");
}


private void RunDiskPart(List<string> commands, string arguments = null)
{
    string diskpartPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "System32", "diskpart.exe");

    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(diskpartPath))
        throw new Exception(String.Format("'{0}' doesn't exist.", diskpartPath));

    Debug.WriteLine("diskpartPath: " + diskpartPath);

    ProcessStartInfo psInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(diskpartPath);

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty (arguments))
        psInfo.Arguments = arguments;

    psInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    psInfo.RedirectStandardError = true; //redirect standard Error
    psInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; //redirect standard output
    psInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    psInfo.UseShellExecute = false; //if True, uses 'ShellExecute'; if false, uses 'CreateProcess'
    psInfo.Verb = "runas"; //use elevated permissions
    psInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

    //create new instance and set properties
    using (Process p = new Process() { EnableRaisingEvents = true, StartInfo = psInfo })
    {
        //subscribe to event and add event handler code
        p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                //ToDo: add desired code 
                Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Data);
            }
        };

        //subscribe to event and add event handler code
        p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                //ToDo: add desired code
                Debug.WriteLine("Output: " + e.Data);
            }
        };

        p.Start(); //start

        p.BeginErrorReadLine(); //begin async reading for standard error
        p.BeginOutputReadLine(); //begin async reading for standard output

        //send input
        foreach (string cmd in commands)
        {
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine(cmd);
        }

        //waits until the process is finished before continuing
        p.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

**Usage** (Clear Readonly):

```
 //The drive letter can be one of the following formats: `H`, `H:`, or `H:\`
DiskClearReadOnly("H:\");
```

**Usage** (Set Readonly):

```
 //The drive letter can be one of the following formats: `H`, `H:`, or `H:\`
DiskSetReadOnly("H:\");
```

---

**Option 3** - PowerShell:

The following shows how to use *PowerShell* to set or clear the readonly attribute for a removable USB drive.

**Download/install the appropriate PowerShell NuGet package**:

**For .NET Framework**, choose one of the following:

- [Microsoft.PowerShell.5.1.ReferenceAssemblies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.5.1.ReferenceAssemblies#supportedframeworks-body-tab)
- [PowerShellStandard.Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PowerShellStandard.Library/7.0.0-preview.1)

**For .NET** (version >= 6), choose one of the following:

- [System.Management.Automation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management.Automation/7.4.0-preview.3)
- [Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK/7.4.0-preview.3#supportedframeworks-body-tab)

See [Choosing the right PowerShell NuGet package for your .NET project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/choosing-the-right-nuget-package?view=powershell-7.3) for more information and [Differences between Windows PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell 7.x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/differences-from-windows-powershell?source=recommendations&view=powershell-7.2)

**Add the following using directives**:

- `using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces`
- `using System.Management.Automation;`
- `using System.Diagnostics;`

```
public static void DiskClearReadOnly(string driveLetter)
{
    RunPowerShellCommand(driveLetter, false);
    Debug.WriteLine($"Disk '{driveLetter}' is now read-write.");
}

public static void DiskClearReadOnly(int driveNumber)
{
    RunPowerShellCommand(driveNumber, false);
    Debug.WriteLine($"Disk '{driveNumber}' is now read-write.");

}
public static void DiskSetReadOnly(string driveLetter)
{
    RunPowerShellCommand(driveLetter, true);
    Debug.WriteLine($"Disk '{driveLetter}' is now read-only.");
}

public static void DiskSetReadOnly(int driveNumber)
{
    RunPowerShellCommand(driveNumber, true);
    Debug.WriteLine($"Disk '{driveNumber}' is now read-only.");
}

private static void RunPowerShellCommand(string driveLetter, bool isReadOnly)
{
    InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
    iss.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.RemoteSigned; //set execution policy

    using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss))
    {
        //open
        runspace.Open();

        using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            ps.Runspace = runspace;

            var psInstance = PowerShell.Create();

            //Get-Partition -DriveLetter <driveLetter>
            psInstance.AddCommand("Get-Partition").AddParameter("DriveLetter", driveLetter);

            //Get-Disk
            psInstance.AddCommand("Get-Disk");

            //Set-Disk -IsReadOnly [True | False]
            psInstance.AddCommand("Set-Disk").AddParameter("IsReadOnly", isReadOnly);

            System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<PSObject> outputCollection = psInstance.Invoke();

            //'Set-Disk' doesn't produce any output, so there won't be any output
            foreach (PSObject outputItem in outputCollection)
            {
                //create reference
                string data = outputItem.BaseObject?.ToString();

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(outputItem.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void RunPowerShellCommand(int diskNumber, bool isReadOnly)
{
    InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
    iss.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.RemoteSigned; //set execution policy

    using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss))
    {
        //open
        runspace.Open();

        using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            ps.Runspace = runspace;

            var psInstance = PowerShell.Create();

            //Get-Disk -Number <diskNumber>
            psInstance.AddCommand("Get-Disk").AddParameter("Number", diskNumber);

            //Set-Disk -IsReadOnly [True | False]
            psInstance.AddCommand("Set-Disk").AddParameter("IsReadOnly", isReadOnly);

            System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<PSObject> outputCollection = psInstance.Invoke();

            //'Set-Disk' doesn't produce any output, so there won't be any output
            foreach (PSObject outputItem in outputCollection)
            {
                //create reference
                string data = outputItem.BaseObject?.ToString();

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(outputItem.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage** (Clear Readonly):

```
 //The drive letter can be one of the following formats: `H`, `H:`, or `H:\`
DiskClearReadOnly("H:\");
```

**Usage** (Set Readonly):

```
 //The drive letter can be one of the following formats: `H`, `H:`, or `H:\`
DiskSetReadOnly("H:\");
```

**Resources**:

- [diskpart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart)
- [System.Diagnostics.Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.8)
- [How to read embedded resource text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file)
- [PowerShell - Adding and invoking commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/adding-and-invoking-commands?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: Thank you for the long explanation. I chose the Option no. 1. I modified the manifest of the project, but when I start the main project and call the second project, the administrator popup doesn't appear. Then an exception will come asking for elevated previledges.
If I start the main project as administrator everything works.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your comments. All of the code above has been tested. The OP doesn't mention anything about multiple projects. Put all of the code above in a single project and test it. If you desire to create multiple projects and find that the code above doesn't work with multiple projects, then create a new post (ie: question) that describes exactly what you're trying to accomplish. _diskpart_ requires administrative privileges, therefore, if you're debugging Visual Studio needs to be opened with Administrator privileges.