# Powershell using from C# console application

Tags: c#, powershell

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   string powershellCommand = @"Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -match 'SOLIDWORKS PDM Client' } | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, InstallLocation | ConvertTo-Json";
   ExecuteScript(powershellCommand);
}

public static void ExecuteScript(string powershellCommand)
{
    var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "powershell.exe",
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            Arguments = $"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command \"{powershellCommand}\""
        };

    using (var process = new Process())
    {
        process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
        process.Start();

        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

        Console.WriteLine("Output:");
        Console.WriteLine(output);

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(error))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error:");
            Console.WriteLine(error);
        }
    }
}
```

I used this code in Windows PowerShell and it works correctly, but in C#, it always returns an empty string - why? Can anybody help? Thanks

If I pass the same script to Windows PowerShell, the output is like this.

Comment: Why do the detour over powershell, when you can access the registry through C#/.Net ?

Comment: Are you running inside Visual Studio?  Try right click VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: Or even if you *really* needed PS why not just use `Powershell.Create` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.create?view=powershellsdk-7.4.0

Comment: When you execute a PowerShell command from a C# application, it runs in a separate process. If the PowerShell command takes a long time to execute or if it waits for more input, `ReadToEnd()` might block indefinitely. You need to read the output and error streams asynchronously.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74005878/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/76258050/10024425